# How to show searchResultsTableView when searchbar is activated?

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am implementing a `UISearchDisplayController` and I would like to populate the `searchResultsTableView` with the content of the tableView (unfiltered) right on load - before text is being entered.

This works when I start entering values in the searchBar.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.isSearching = YES;

    //tell the searchDisplayTableView to show here!

    [controller.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.isSearching = NO;
    [controller.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Would anybody have any pointers into the right direction?

**Please don't reply with "don't do that" or "Apple did not design the control that way." or ...**

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Has anyone worked out how to do this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's control works like that. I solved it by implementing a separate controller (call it search display controller) object that is a search bar delegate and applies a predicate to the datasource. This way the tableview is filtered 'inline'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your table view using the filtered result when searching is doing:
In this method just call table view `reloadData`:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.isSearching = YES;
    [yourTableView reloadData];
    [controller.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

And modify your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(isSearching == YES)
   {
        yourDataArray = //filtered result;
   }
   else
   {
        yourDataAray = //unfiltered result;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Hi Midhun, thanks for your comment but it does not quite work that way. When I activate the search, the searchDisplayController is dimming the tableView (though we still see content but cannot control it). When text is entered in the searchBar, the searchDisplayTableView is loaded with the (filtered or not, this I can control) content, I want to show.

Comment: @Ronny: when you start typing the table view is dimming, after typing a single letter the table view comes to previous state (not dimmed). I think it is your problem, am I correct?

Comment: @Ronny: are you still having the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    // Here is a table we want to show in UISearchDisplayController
    XXRecentSearchDataSource *recentSearch = [XXRecentSearchDataSource recentSearchDataSource];
    recentSearch.delegate = self;

    // Setup default table view
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                       CGRectGetMaxY(controller.searchBar.frame),
                       CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),
                       CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(controller.searchBar.bounds));

    // Setup temporary table and remember it for future use
    [_tempRecentSearchTableView release];
    _tempRecentSearchTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame
                                                               style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tempRecentSearchTableView.dataSource = recentSearch;
    _tempRecentSearchTableView.delegate = recentSearch;

    [self performSelector:@selector(removeOverlay) withObject:nil afterDelay:.0f];
}

- (void)removeOverlay
{
    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:_tempRecentSearchTableView];
}
```

You must remember to remove _tempRecentSearchTableView in some cases. For example:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    // Remove temporary table view
    [_tempRecentSearchTableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you know if the searchbar has focus.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([_searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
              return [_filteredData count];
    } else {

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }
}
```

When configuring the cell do the same question

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Entidad *e = nil;

    if ([_searchBar isFirstResponder])
    {
        e = [self.filteredData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        e = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = e.titulo;
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"password-50.png"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = e.sitio;

    return cell;
}
```

Set the filter parameters

```
-(void)filter:(NSString*)text
{

    _filteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Entidad" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"titulo" ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    if(text.length > 0)
    {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(titulo CONTAINS[c] %@)", text];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error;


    NSArray* loadedEntities = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    _filteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:loadedEntities];

    NSLog(@"%@", _filteredData);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    [self filter:text];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [self filter:@""];

    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [_searchBar setText:@""];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I hope to serve you, my English is very limited